# How to remove characters in parentheses including parentheses '[word]sample ' -> sample in python

Tags: python, dataframe, replace

In dataframe, I don't know how to remove the words including parentheses.

for example in dataframe :

sentence             contents
[abc]asdf            [asdf]sssss
[abs]sdfg            [asdfs]dfax

==> result
sentence             contents
asdf                 sssss
sdfg                 dfax

I tried

`df['sentence'] = df['sentence'].str.replace("[^[a-zA-Z0-9]]", "")`

but it didn't work.

please help me,

thanks

Comment: I think you're looking for `\\[[\w]+\\]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

df['sentence'] = df['sentence'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\[\w+\]', '', x))
```